# Can Vue.Draggable be used with Vuetify v-data-table and allow utilisation of table v-slot:item.<name>?

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable, v-data-table

Vuetify `v-data-table` supports several types of slots: `v-slot:body`, `v-slot:item` and `v-slot:item.<name>`.

We have been using `v-slot:item.<name>` extensively, as these provides a flexible way to style and process content in individual columns AND allow the table headers to be programmatically changed.

I'd like to add draggability to my `v-data-table` rows and have got this working using [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable).

However the `draggable` component requires use of the `v-data-table` `v-slot:body` i.e. taking control of the full body of the table and thereby losing the flexibility of `v-slot:item.<name>`.

Is there a way these two components can be used together and provide `v-slot:item.<name>` support?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have created a `DataTableRowHandler` component which allows `v-slot:item.<name>` support.

This is placed inside the `draggable` component, inserts the table `<tr>` element and feeds off the same "headers" array to insert `<td>` elements and `v-slot:item.<name>` entries.  If no `v-slot:item.<name>` is defined then the cell value is output, in the same way that `v-data-table` works.

Here is the example component usage:

```
<v-data-table
  ref="myTable"
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  item-key="name"
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <draggable
      :list="props.items"
      tag="tbody"
      :disabled="!allowDrag"
      :move="onMoveCallback"
      :clone="onCloneCallback"
      @end="onDropCallback"
    >
      <data-table-row-handler
        v-for="(item, index) in props.items"
        :key="index"
        :item="item"
        :headers="headers"
        :item-class="getClass(item)"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.lock="{ item }">
          <v-icon @click="item.locked = item.locked ? false : true">{{
            item.locked ? "mdi-pin-outline" : "mdi-pin-off-outline"
          }}</v-icon>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.carbs="{ item }">
          {{ item.carbs }}
          <v-icon>{{
            item.carbs > 80
              ? "mdi-speedometer"
              : item.carbs > 45
              ? "mdi-speedometer-medium"
              : "mdi-speedometer-slow"
          }}</v-icon>
        </template>
      </data-table-row-handler>
    </draggable>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Here is the `DataTableRowHandler` component code

```
<template>
  <tr :class="getClass">
    <td v-for="(header, index) in headers" :key="index">
      <slot :item="item" :name="columnName(header)">
        <div :style="getAlignment(header)">
          {{ getNonSlotValue(item, header) }}
        </div>
      </slot>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DataTableRowHandler",
  components: {},
  props: {
    itemClass: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {};
      },
    },
    headers: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => {
        return [];
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    getClass() {
      return this.itemClass;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    columnName(header) {
      return `item.${header.value}`;
    },
    getAlignment(header) {
      const align = header.align ? header.align : "right";
      return `text-align: ${align}`;
    },
    getNonSlotValue(item, header) {
      const val = item[header.value];

      if (val) {
        return val;
      }

      return "";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

An example of it's use is in this [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-v-data-tables-draggable-with-slots-1lecb?file=/src/components/DataTable.vue)

Comment: What should I do to make the loading animation work?

Comment: In Vuetify 3 this is no longer working properly because the body slot is placed within the tbody. Adding the below example causes two tbodys to render which breaks the styling.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/42acb0c8a2a39f718b443532db41fb4ad1544305/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.ts#L539) of `VDataTable` and found that the content in `tbody` is generated by `genItems()`.

The following example is implemented with functional components and is fully compatible with `v-slot:item*`:

```html
<v-data-table ref="table" ...>
    <template #body="props">
        <draggable
            v-if="$refs.table"
            tag="tbody"
            :list="props.items"
        >
            <v-nodes :vnodes="$refs.table.genItems(props.items, props)" />
        </draggable>
    </template>

    <template #item.name="{ item }">
    ...
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Here is the definition of the `VNodes` component:

```js
components: {
    VNodes: {
      functional: true,
      render: (h, ctx) => ctx.props.vnodes,
    }
}
```